# ODBC DSN slows MSSQL to timeouts

Tags: python, .net, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

There is a multi-million record database in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 under Windows XP SP3.

My co-worker has written a .Net application, which directly connects to this db and runs a reasonable amount of queries. I dont know .Net, but I'm sure this app does not connect to DB using ODBC.

On the other hand I've written a command-line python (CPython version 2.7.5) application, which connects to this database and runs simple queries on it to send the data over internet to somewhere else. Database connection is made using pyodbc 3.0.7 (installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and a DSN which uses `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` driver. I've tried both disabling and enabling connection pools for this driver in `Connection Pooling` tab of windows `Data Sources (ODBC)` applet. The script sends 100 records from the db and then closes the connection and sleeps for 2 minutes and then runs again.

Both of these programs run constantly on the same machine as db.

The question is the .Net app runs nicely when I remove the defined DSN ( and of course the python script is not running). When I define the DSN again and start the python script to run side by side .Net app, there is no problem for roughly 5 hours. but then gradually while python script is mostly fine, the .Net app starts to get timeouts from the db.

What could go wrong that this happens?

EDIT:

python script (which connects using ODBC) runs fine, all the time. but .Net app falls behind of usual performance after couple of hours. When I close the python script, .Net app still stays behind. but when I remove the ODBC DSN which I defined for python script, .Net app goes back to normal performance. It's very strange. As I said I don't know anything about .Net, so this could be result of non-standard code on the part of .Net app, maybe open transactions, locks, too many connections, etc. To make the case stranger, cutting database size to half by deleting records and rebuilding indexes, seems to have solved the .Net app issue so far.

EDIT 2:

The only two queries that python script runs, are:

```
SELECT TOP 100 FROM tbl_data WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE id = ?
```

The first query usually only runs once in each run of the python script. The second one runs at most 100 times. `id` is primary key, and so is indexed. As you can see the queries could not be simpler. For the first query I read the entire result set in the program to not keep a cursor open on DB server. Also I've turned off connection pooling in ODBC applet for the driver I'm using, so after each run of the script, DB connection should have been disposed and all resources on DB server should have been freed. The script sleeps for 2 minutes and then repeats this.

The queries that .Net app runs are far more complex, combined with some triggers on the database. And the strange thing is it runs mostly fine, on itself. but when DSN is defined, it starts to get long waits on a single insert statement, which sometimes results in timeout.

Also I should have said that Windows and MSSQL are not updated with latest patches from microsoft, so if it's a bug in ODBC driver or MSSQL itself, it could have been already solved for others.

EDIT 3

Table is clustered on PK index. the data table contains about 1.5M records now. DB size is about 160GB. Server does not have a high spec. Intel Core i7 2600, 4GB RAM, plain 1TB SATA disk drive.

Comment: Great thanks for the update.  Is the primary key clustered or nonclustered?  Also how big is this server (memory,cpu,etc..)?

Comment: Based on everything you are describing it looks like your python (ODBC) application is blocking the .Net application due to resource contention.  Timeouts can only be caused by a few things, resource contention, long running queries, and blocking are the usual suspects.  When performance is degraded have you looked at the active connections to see if there is a blocking problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that can be affecting performance.  There could be resource contention, sub-optimal SQL Server configuration, slow disks, missing indexes etc...

I would start by monitoring the system resources when both processes are running.  You can use perfmon to monitor the OS and SQL counters.  I would start by looking at

- ProcessorInformation/%ProcessorTime

  LogicalDisk/Avg Disk sec/read

  LogicalDisk/Avg Disk sec/write

  Memory/Available MBytes

  SQLServerBufferManager/BufferCacheHitRatio

  SQLServerBufferManager/PageLifeExpectency

Here is a great article on using perfmon, http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/

The next step is optimizing query and SQL Server performance.

Query Performance, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx
SQL Server Performance,

- -Separate data and log files on different volumes (raid 10 is preferable)

  -tempdb (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527(v=SQL.105).aspx)

  -configure min/max memory

  -configure lock pages in memory and instant file initialization

  -Check out this link, http://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-performance-tuning/

The point is that there are so many possibilities that could be affecting your database, that it is nearly impossible to identify your problem based on the provided information.  I recommend that you go through each of these items to identify why your system is not running optimally.

Comment: Thanks for helpful info, but as I said, .Net app runs fine, when there is no ODBC DSN. so I guess the problem should have something to do with ODBC. meanwhile I'm rewriting the script to directly connect to mssql using pymssql library which uses mssql C API under the hood. If that works, there **must** be something fishy about ODBC.

Comment: What makes you believe the ODBC DSN is the likely culprit? Did you take the query you are running via the ODBC DSN and run it directly in SQL Server? If yes, did it run significantly faster? I am trying to figure out how you came to this conclusion.  Your conclusion may be correct, I just want to understand what you have and have not tried.

Comment: Have you ruled out that the ODBC application is causing performance to become degraded in the .Net Application over time?  I think this is more likely the case.  When performance becomes degraded, what do you see in SQL Server, blocking? large waits? memory paging? index fragmentation? high IO?  Your problem could be to the ODBC driver, but I think the more likely case is that the ODBC APP is affecting your other application.